# How do I find out more about Salesforce.com as a CRM platform

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I am totally new to Salesforce.com where can I find information about it?

Comment: Your question if too vague to get a clear answer. The first answer would be simply to the demos and help site on SF. But than again, that's itself might scare you for the amount of data you will get. Try a more detailed question or subject you are interested. This might give you some related answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you to get touch with salesforce
http://salesforcedeveloperblog.blogspot.in/2011/05/basic-salesforce-knowledge.html
http://www.salesforce.com/customer-resources/learning-center/details/best-practices/understanding-the-basic-building.jsp
http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_Basic-Premier-Support.pdf

Answer (score 0):

These links would help you understand the Salesforce CRM functionality. It covers what's a CRM and how Salesforce fits into that category.

http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/what-is-crm.jsp
http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/products.jsp

The most common confusion that most newbies have is the difference between Salesforce and force.com. This link would help you understand that

http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000btOsEAI